# Incomplete data retrieval json in react native

Tags: reactjs, json

I've developed an invoice app that allows me to select items, register their information in a database, and then view all the chosen items on a page. However, I'm facing an issue where not all records are displayed until I manually refresh the flatlist. The same problem occurs when I attempt to retrieve the sum amount; it displays the total of all previously entered records until I refresh the page. I'm hoping to find a solution to this issue and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: How can we help without seeing any code? Any components, states, etc? How can we reproduce your error? Give us at least something to look at.